# Leaflet add/remove legends with layer selection

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, layer, legend

I'm new to Leaflet/JavaScript and have been struggling to get legends a map to show only when a specific layers is selected from the layer control. I have three layers, one of which I would like to have no legend and two others that have a corresponding legend. I came across an example, but have not been able to make it work:

```js
// Add and remove legend from layers
  map.on('overlayadd', function (eventLayer) {
  // Switch to the Permafrost legend...
  if (eventLayer.name === 'Permafrost') {
    this.removeControl(legend1);
    legend2.addTo(this);
  } else { // Or switch to the treeline legend...
    this.removeControl(legend2);
    legend1.addTo(this);
}});
```

I created a jsfiddle with the specific example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gerlis/T8DHb/3/

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your code needed just a couple of changes. Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/T8DHb/8/

When you change the base layer, the even fired is not 'overlayadd', it is 'baselayerchange':

```
map.on('baselayerchange', function (eventLayer) {
```

You should only add to map the layer which you want to show for the default base layer. I added PermaFrost.

Also, you should only add to the map the legend which you want to go with the default base layer.

Comment: I noticed that your solution takes several selections of the layers for the action to take effect. What I actually would like is to have no legend of the "Satellite", legend2 with 'Permafrost" and legend1 with "Treeline".

Comment: I tried a nested conditional statement: `map.on('baselayerchange', function (eventLayer) {     if (eventLayer.name === 'Permafrost') {         map.removeControl(legend1);         legend2.addTo(map);     } else { if (eventLayer.name === 'Treeline'){         map.removeControl(legend2);         legend1.addTo(map);     } else {map.removeControl(legend1);map.removeControl(legend2);}});` which did not work.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know which legend you want with which layer. The problem with you having to double select the base layer had to do with you adding all three baseLayers to the map. I edited the fiddle so that by default only PermaFrost layer is added to the map (and nothing else): http://jsfiddle.net/T8DHb/8/