# Show Different Legend When Changing Layer - leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, gis

I'm trying to make my leaflet map show no legend when both layers are selected, and when only one layer is selected show that layer's legend.

I found these solutions using Javascript:

- [How to switch between multiple map legends with leaflet.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051680/how-to-switch-between-multiple-map-legends-with-leaflet-js)
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92257/leaflet-add-and-remove-legends-with-layer-selection

But I haven't been able to figure out how to apply these techniques in R. Can anyone point me to a document to read, or could give me a hint?

Here is some test data:

```
df1
  Tickets      long      lat
1      28 -71.12088 42.37418
2       4 -71.09524 42.36911
3       3 -71.11935 42.38532
df2 
  Tickets     long      lat
4      33 -71.1213 42.37401
5       1 -71.0915 42.37255
6      21 -71.1226 42.37512
7       1 -71.1016 42.36411
```

Here is a snippet of code:

```
base_map <- leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles('Stamen.TonerLite') %>% 
  setView(-71.128184, 42.3769824, zoom = 14)

pal1 <- colorNumeric(palette = "RdBu",
                    domain = df1$Tickets)
pal2 <- colorNumeric(palette = "RdBu",
                    domain = df2$Tickets)

base_map %>% 
    addCircles(data = df1, lng = df1$long, lat = df1$lat,
               color = pal1(df1$Tickets), radius = 5, group = "Group 1 Dots") %>%
    addLegend("bottomright", pal = pal1, values = df1$Tickets,
               title = "1 Dots") %>%
    addCircles(data = df2, lng = df2$long, lat = df2$lat,
               color = pal2(df2$Tickets), radius = 5, group = "Group 2 Dots") %>%
    addLegend("bottomright", pal = pal2, values = df2$Tickets,
               title = "2 Dots") %>%
    addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("Group 1 Dots", "Group 2 Dots"),
                     options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `group="Group Name"` to your call to `addLegend()`, which should then allow you to toggle the corresponding legends anytime you turn a layer on/off.

```
library(leaflet)

df1 <- data.frame(
  Tickets = c(28, 4, 3),
  long = c(-71.12088,-71.09524,-71.11935),
  lat = c(42.37418, 42.36911, 42.38532)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  Tickets = c(33, 1, 21, 1),
  long = c(-71.1213,-71.0915,-71.1226,-71.1016),
  lat = c(42.37401, 42.37255, 42.37512, 42.36411)
)

base_map <- leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Voyager") %>%
  setView(-71.128184, 42.3769824, zoom = 14)

pal1 <- colorNumeric(palette = "RdBu",
                     domain = df1$Tickets)

pal2 <- colorNumeric(palette = "RdBu",
                     domain = df2$Tickets)

base_map |>
  addCircles(
    data = df1,
    lng = df1$long,
    lat = df1$lat,
    color = pal1(df1$Tickets),
    radius = 5,
    group = "Group 1 Dots"
  ) %>%
  addLegend(
    "bottomright",
    pal = pal1,
    values = df1$Tickets,
    title = "1 Dots",
    group = "Group 1 Dots"
  ) %>%
  addCircles(
    data = df2,
    lng = df2$long,
    lat = df2$lat,
    color = pal2(df2$Tickets),
    radius = 5,
    group = "Group 2 Dots"
  ) %>%
  addLegend(
    "bottomright",
    pal = pal2,
    values = df2$Tickets,
    title = "2 Dots",
    group = "Group 2 Dots"
  ) %>%
  addLayersControl(
    overlayGroups = c("Group 1 Dots", "Group 2 Dots"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
  )
```